# Error: Please install tedious package manually

Tags: node.js, sequelize-js, electron

Estou tentando fazer um projeto em Node.js / Electron e preciso pegar informações de um banco SQL Server. Quando executo a linha abaixo, aparece o erro:

```
const db = new Sequelize('banco', 'sa', 'xxyyuuu',{dialect:"mssql", host: "servidor"});
```

---

```
Uncaught Exception: Error: Please install tedious package manually
    at ConnectionManager._loadDialectModule (webpack:///./node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js?:81:15)
    at new ConnectionManager (webpack:///./node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mssql/connection-manager.js?:16:21)
    at new MssqlDialect (webpack:///./node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mssql/index.js?:15:30)
    at new Sequelize (webpack:///./node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js?:340:20)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/backend/db.js?:3:12)
    at Object../src/backend/db.js (C:\laragon\www\kds-vue\dist_electron\index.js:8609:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\laragon\www\kds-vue\dist_electron\index.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/backend/index.js?:2:13)
    at Object../src/backend/index.js (C:\laragon\www\kds-vue\dist_electron\index.js:8620:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\laragon\www\kds-vue\dist_electron\index.js:20:30)
```

Já reinstalei tudo em um novo diretório e não consegui achar uma solução.

Comment: Essa [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11168#issuecomment-731108695) ajuda?

Answer (score 0):

Com base no [link](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11168#issuecomment-731108695) citado nos comentários, fiz o seguinte para resolver:

Criei um arquivo chamado db.js com o seguinte código:

```
import * as tedious from 'tedious';

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = new Sequelize('banco', 'usuario', 'senha',{dialect:"mssql", dialectModule : tedious, host: "hostdb"});

export {
    db
}
```

O que fiz de diferente:

- `import * as tedious from 'tedious';`
- `dialectModule : tedious`
- `export { db }`

Isso resolveu o problema.